# What provides the clock signal in CSI2 interface?

Tags: computer-architecture, camera, csi, mipi

What provides the clock signal for the CSI2 interface used for many cameras? Does the camera provide it or is it the processor the camera is interfacing to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIPI CSI-2 data clock comes from the camera as a separate pair (D-PHY) or encoded with the signal (C-PHY).

In D-PHY both clock edges are used to sample data from the data lanes. In C-PHY every trio change-of-state encodes a clock and a multi-bit symbol, this clock is recovered by the receiver.

Now, let’s talk about the camera timebase.

Normally, the camera reference clock, or timebase, originates from the camera itself from a local crystal oscillator. This reference isn’t output by the camera directly, but the delivered data rate and frame rate would be related to it.

The host can optionally provide a reference clock to the camera, separate from the MIPI data signals, as a timebase reference. 24MHz is common.

Another method is to provide a frame sync or trigger signal to the camera. The camera will send its frame each time it is triggered.

Either way, this host-driven reference is typically used for multi-camera setups to synchronize the frames (e.g., for stereo, multi-focal or surround cameras.)

Comment: I was wondering about this, I don't understand why the host doesn't drive the clock since it would make time syncing a lot easier. There are different ways people try to synchronize the IMX219 cameras on the jetson nano but unless there is some way to have them share a clock it's basically not possible for them to stay synced due to oscillator drift between them.

Comment: I believe the Nano can provide reference clocks and/or frame sync to its CSI-2 ports. There are pins allocated on the connectors for this purpose. R.pi camera connectors also have extra signals that can be used for clock or frame sync.

Comment: I confirmed that the Nano provides MCLK to its CSI-2 header. MCLK. Typically around 24MHz. Check with NVidia on how to enable it. In my opinion it's not as good of an option as providing a frame sync signal, because even with a shared timebase the frames could still be not aligned closely. And, at 24MHz, it's a noise source getting kicked to the camera.

Comment: Raspberry pi has an MCLK and generic GPIO, the latter which can be defined by the user.

Comment: It looks like the cameras use their own 24Mhz oscillator, maybe this means it's not possible to use the system clock.

Comment: You would need to change the camera setting to accept the external reference clock.

Comment: This may be of interest: https://www.arducam.com/jetson-nano-stereo-camera-sync-issue-arducam/

Comment: Yeah thanks, I have a couple monochrome cameras with external trigger I will use but it was a very odd design choice. The new Pi Camera lets you sync through connecting a couple wires. I have a stereo board for the IMX219 but they didn't tie the clocks together which was very odd - could have tweaked it a little and had synchronized system.